# Image width is not appearing 100% for small screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have hero section which has text on the left side and image on the right.Used display flex and in small screen image should stack on text. I am wrapping image in div. I am making image width 100% in css still image is not 100% in responsive mode.

```
import React  from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
   
class Res extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="hero-section p-3">
                    <div className="container row">
                        <div className="hero-text">
                            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Title Here </h2>
                            <p>This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test text This is simple test textv This is simple test text</p>
                            <button className="blog-button"> Click  </button>
                        </div>
                
                        <div className="hero-img">
                            <img className="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490750967868-88aa4486c946?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8Zmxvd2VyfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60"alt="random image" />
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Res;

.hero-text{
  width:60%;  
}
.hero-section{
  background-color: #6C887E;
  color:beige;

}
.container{
width:80%;
padding: 2em;
max-width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.hero-text{
  width:60%;  
}
button{
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 0.6em 1.4em;
  border-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hero-img{
  width:30%;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you make a codepen of this so we can fix it?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-banach-60gvc?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: You can check link is for Sandbox.

Comment: theres nothing at that link. i dont think you saved it